# if a row exists in sql it should not perform an update

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query that based on a condition updates a table with multiple rows.But every time i run the query it copies all the same data over again:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
 INSERT INTO table(ID,NameID,tag)
SELECT 
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table) + ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY ID),

     50000,
     tag
FROM Table
WHERE NameID = 10000
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF
```

so everytime the above query runs it copies the data with the nameID 10000 and puts it in a new rows with the nameID of 50000 and increments the ID.
so if this query runs the first time it will work fine the second time it runs it does the following

```
ID   |NameId  |tag
10   |100000  |4589
15   |100000  |7879
16   |500000  |4589 // first run of query gets the data which i wanted
17   |500000  |7879
18   |500000  |4589 // second run off query adds the same data over again
19   |500000  |7879
```

how can i tell it to check if 50000 exists in the table dont do an insert?

Comment: Also research the `merge` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you are turning identity insert off.  That seems to defeat the purpose of an `identity` column.  But, that is not central to your question.

You can use `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, NameID, tag)
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table) + ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY ID),
           50000, tag
    FROM Table t
    WHERE NameID = 10000 AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.NameId = t50000 AND t2.tag = t.tag);
```

Comment: i set it off,because the table was currently set to off at first,so i thought it would be safer to switch it back off after im done instead of leaving it on.I could be wrong i just thought it was a safer move

Comment: @Sarah . . . You should always leave the identity insert on.  Really, the only exception is when you are re-loading the table and want to preserve the values from the previous version of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can use "if not exists" this case

```
if not exists("condition") begin
"insert"
end
```